# Segregating two rows with different data into two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Data as follows in the following fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c687d

Trying to segregate column of phone number based on phone type.

**Following is the input**

```
| LastName | PhoneNameType | PhoneNumber |
|----------|---------------|-------------|
| KRANSLER | Work          | 8326244229  |
| KRANSLER | Mobile        | 7239876     |
| GILBERT  | Work          | 2121806     |
| GILBERT  | Mobile        | 8406582     |
| LITZ     | Work          | 3462590784  |
| LITZ     | Mobile        | 2816284631  |
```

**Output should be as follows**

```
| LastName | WorkNumber | MobileNumber |
|----------|------------|--------------|
| GILBERT  | 2121806    | 8406582      |
| KRANSLER | 8326244229 | 7239876      |
| LITZ     | 3462590784 | 2816284631   |
```

Comment: what the output?

Comment: Post the data and structure here, too.

Comment: Updated the question with data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more option with conditional aggregation. (Works as expected when there is at most one row per type per name)

```
SELECT LastName
,max(case when phonenametype='Work' then phonenumber end) as worknumber
,max(case when phonenametype='Mobile' then phonenumber end) as mobilenumber
FROM tempo
GROUP BY LastName
```